# Where should I add the necessary code to add an extra attribute to the kses allowed tags array?

Tags: plugins, configuration

In trying to post an article on one of the new SE blogs, I came across the following problem.  I'm listed as an *author* which means that my abilities are somewhat restricted.  In particular, I'm not allowed to post *arbitrary* HTML, rather my entries are sent through the kses parser first.  This seems a Good Thing in general (I don't want to be held responsible for the HTML!) but it interferes with one piece of the Markdown processor: quotes.  I can't write:

```
> this is a quote
```

because the `>` gets escaped by the kses routines.  Now, modifying the kses code to allow that through is tricky, and is the Wrong Solution (because it would make the `kses` parser knit too tightly to the Markdown one; actually, the Right Solution would be to validate the data *after* it had been processed, but never mind ...).  This isn't a big problem because, of course, I can just use the `<blockquote>...</blockquote>` tags directly.  Only that turns off the Markdown processor inside it.  Since we're using PHPMarkdownExtra (at least, tests seem to indicate that we are), I can use the `markdown="1"` fake attribute to turn on Markdown inside the blockquote.  But this gets taken out by kses as it's not on the list of approved attributes!

However, adding `markdown` to the list of approved attributes seems much easier than adding support for the `> quote` syntax; in particular there is an array `$allowedposttags` that holds this information so it would mean simply changing that array in an obvious way.

But, and this is the question, where is the right place to do that modification?  Clearly, modifying `kses.php` is the Last Resort.  My *guess* would be that the Right Place would be for the `markdown.php` file to do this modification (since that's the file that knows that Markdown is going to be used).  But if I don't want to change anything that might be changed upstream, where should I put the required change?

(When I say "I" in the above, I don't actually mean "me" since I want this to be changed on the SE blogs; so please explain it in language that Rebecca Chernoff can understand!)

Answer (score 1):

In detail there's the constant `CUSTOM_TAGS` that allowes defining `$allowedposttags, $allowedtags, $allowedentitynames`.

Then you can simply set `CUSTOM_TAGS` to true and define the globals in a function hooked before kses gets included.

*The first available hook to fire an action that defines `$allowedposttags` would be `muplugins_loaded`, but I don't know if kses is loaded before or after it.*

```
// Set custom tags to override $allowedposttags, $allowedtags, $allowedentitynames
if ( ! defined( 'CUSTOM_TAGS' ) )
    define( 'CUSTOM_TAGS', true );
```

You also got the `wp_kses_hook()` that contains a self explanatory filter:

```
apply_filters('pre_kses', $string, $allowed_html, $allowed_protocols);
```

Comment: Looking at the code, I wasn't sure that `CUSTOM_TAGS` actually _defined_ `$allowedposttags` but rather that it stopped kses defining it itself (so preventing kses overwriting an earlier definition).  You still have to actually define it.  Also, my question was: _where_, meaning "in what file", should I put the new definition of `$allowedposttags`?  My apologies if this was not clear.

Comment: Write a plugin and hook it as early as possible.

Comment: You'd want to define the constant before **kses.php** is included(technically it's a `require_once` call, but you get the point) by **wp-settings.php** ... the require happens before any actions in **wp-settings.php** though, so i'd suggest trying the config file(seems strange, but i'd consider it appropriate due to the load sequence of core WordPress files). Else you'll fire on an action that occurs after kses has been included and defined the data already..

Comment: ... the more ideal solution might be to hook the kses filter instead, so you don't have to define the tags using the constant.

Comment: @t31os: I guess that if I _know_ my file is loaded after `kses.php` then I can redefine `$allowedposttags` as I wish: the danger was that `kses.php` would overwrite my changes (in fact, defining it afterwards has some advantages as I only need to add the changes rather than define the whole array).  Still, where to put plugin configurations isn't clear to me.

Comment: Run a filter on `pre_kses`?

Comment: see edit/update of a